# Compare two documents and change text color

Tags: c#, colors, richtextbox, match

I am looking to compare 2 files using RichTextBoxes and upload them into new RichTextBoxes with the certain text that is the same in green and the different text in red.

What I mean is:

### ***DOCUMENT 1***

```
C1    147417 111.111 222.222 0 TEXT
U13   IC-123456 1234 9876 360 TEXT
R123 13866 -99.9 123.456 100 TEXT
U24   IC-123456 -14 -50 90 TEXT
............more lines............
```

### ***DOCUMENT 2***

```
1   U13  IC-123456   SOMETEXT   1.00   EA P C n   Y
                     EC5547,3-UP                 50
1   U24  IC-123456   SOMETEXT   1.00   EA P C n   Y
                     EC5547,3-UP                 50
1   C1  147417   TEXT   2.00   EA P C n   Y
                 0603,EC0303             50
1   R123  138666   MORETEXT   2.00 EA P C n   Y
                                             50
......................more lines..........................
```

---

And I would like to match the ***1st and 2nd columns*** in the first file to see if they exist on any line in the second file. If they match, the matched items would turn the matched text green and everything else red.

- Is there anyway to do this?
- How could I go about comparing the 1st to columns in a different file?
- Is it possible to change the color of text in a RTB and not the entire line?

### ***EDIT:***

```
    private void checkMatchesInGCandBOM()
    {
        // Splits the text up to compare with the other text.
        var combinedSplit = combinedPlacementsRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

        string[] splitLines;

        foreach (var line in combinedSplit)
        {
            Match theMatch = Regex.Match(line, @"^.*");

            if (theMatch.Success)
            {
                // Stores the matched value in string output.
                string output = theMatch.Value;

                // Replaces the tabs with spaces.
                output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\s+", " ");
                splitLines = output.Split(' ');

                int pos = 0, pos2 = 0;
                pos = bomRichTextBox.Find(splitLines[0], pos, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                pos2 = bomRichTextBox.Find(splitLines[1], pos2, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);

                while (pos != -1)
                {
                    if (bomRichTextBox.SelectedText == splitLines[0] && bomRichTextBox.SelectedText != "")
                    {
                        int my1stPosition = bomRichTextBox.Find(splitLines[1]);
                        bomRichTextBox.SelectionStart = my1stPosition;
                        bomRichTextBox.SelectionLength = splitLines[0].Length;
                        bomRichTextBox.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Underline);
                        bomRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
                    }

                    pos = bomRichTextBox.Find(splitLines[0], pos + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                }

                while (pos2 != -1)
                {
                    if (bomRichTextBox.SelectedText == splitLines[1] && bomRichTextBox.SelectedText != "")
                    {
                        int my1stPosition = bomRichTextBox.Find(splitLines[0]);
                        bomRichTextBox.SelectionStart = my1stPosition;
                        bomRichTextBox.SelectionLength = splitLines[1].Length;
                        bomRichTextBox.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Underline);
                        bomRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                    }

                    pos2 = bomRichTextBox.Find(splitLines[1], pos2 + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
                }
            }
        }
```

However, this does not seem to be working properly....!

All of the columns on the far left should have been ***COMPLETELY*** green but for some reason some are black and some are black and green. Also the next column should have been found everything and changed the color to complete blue..[This is what it turned out to look like using the code above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm986.png)

[New screenshot of what happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWAry.png)

Comment: Could you give a bit more info? How are your documents formatted? Are they flat with n chars between each new column? Tab delimited?

Comment: They are space delimited but I formatted them above with 3 to make it more readable. The columns are also not fixed width.

Comment: Assuming the first two columns are space delimited as you say, you can do a split on spaces and create your search string with the first two elements of the array. Things can get really messy really quick if your data isn't consistent, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a process that pulls the original values that you want line-by-line. It doesn't look like your file is in a flat format and doesn't use delimiters, so pulling those values might be a bit tricky... You mentioned in the comments that our data is space delimited. In this case you can do a split on spaces and create your search string with the first two elements of the array.

Once you have a way to separate those columns from the rest of your document, cycle through and call something something like this:

```
if (richTextBox2.Find(mystring)>0)
{
    int my1stPosition=richTextBox1.Find(strSearch);
    richTextBox2.SelectionStart=my1stPosition;
    richTextBox2.SelectionLength=strSearch.Length;
    richTextBox2.SelectionFont=fnt;
    richTextBox2.SelectionColor=Color.Green;
}
```

(code mostly taken from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/651faf9b-ae32-4c99-b619-d3afd89477e1/)

The "SelectionColor" basically tells the RTB to change the color of the selected text. You are making the program automatically select the text for you with "SelectionStart" and "SelectionLength".

Obviously change the font params to whatever you'd like. If you want to highlight the rest of the document red, you might want to consider making the new RTB red by default, since it sounds as if it's only used for the comparison.

The above will only work for the first occurrence. If you want it to highlight ALL occurrences, you might want to check out IndexOfAll. See this page for more info: http://www.dijksterhuis.org/manipulating-strings-in-csharp-finding-all-occurrences-of-a-string-within-another-string/

IndexOfAll will return an array with a list of each position a substring lies in another string. Once you find these, loop through the array and use the same code that's listed above to change the color of each set.

Comment: I am trying to get this to work and this is what I have so far to try to check each line.. however it is not working properly.. ***(check above in my post edit)***

Comment: Try taking a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I edited the above post again. We are getting closer to figuring this out!! Just another error I am unsure about

Comment: Also using your code it seems to match a *value* properly for the most part...However.. an error I have come across.. let's say that value is **C42** and later on in text it finds **C4**. It will not turn that one (C4) *blue* even if it is matched. However, if it finds **C45** after C42 and/or C4, it ***will*** turn that one (C45) blue...

Comment: I would just place some break points to check the value of the first element. Step through and verify that it's splitting those values appropriately. While it does seem like the program is getting closer to being functional, I probably would have structured it a bit differently. Also, how are you assigning a starting point for your text selection?

Comment: I updated the code above again. It turns out a little different than before. How would you have structured it because my way is not working! :P haha. Also, I need to check if one of them matches than the next 1 in the same line matches and I am not sure how to go about that.

Comment: If you'd like me to take a look at the actual project, shoot me an email at the address listed on my account. It's rather difficult to diagnose this without being able to see it in full. If you'd rather not, then I still suggest setting breakpoints and monitoring the values of your variables and the results of your match/find operations.

Comment: HairyCow19 at gmail. Lengthy back-and-forth discussions are frowned upon at SO, so we can speak via email and you can update your post when an answer is reached.